# searching not null condition in multiple columns with query postgresql

Tags: postgresql, filter, multiple-columns

I want to count how many document that does not have date in field1, field2, field3, and field4. I have created the query as below but it does not really look good.

```
select 
   count(doc)
where true
   and field1 is not null
   and field2 is not null
   and field3 is not null
   and field4 is not null
```

How can I apply one filter for multiple columns?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing at all wrong with your current query, and it is probably what I would be using here.  However, you could use a `COALESCE` trick here:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM yourTable
WHERE COALESCE(field1, field2, field3, field4) IS NOT NULL;
```

This works because for any record having at least one of the four fields assigned to a non `NULL` date would fail the `IS NOT NULL` check.  Only records for which all four fields are `NULL` would match.

Note that this counts records having at least one non `NULL` field.  If instead you want to count records where all four fields are `NULL`, then use:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM yourTable
WHERE COALESCE(field1, field2, field3, field4) IS NULL;
```